# Converting nested JSON strings into JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am consuming an AEM content API and it gives a JSON Structure, but for particular nested nodes, like links, it gives a JSON string in response.

Sample payload -

```js
{
  "Page Title": "Home",
  "Page Description": "Sample Description",
  "Key Words": "test1, test2, test 3",
  "sections": [{
    "Lineup": {
      "title": "Our Project Family",
      "strategy": [{
        "title": "ASHJASH BASED",
        "description": "This is a short description",
        "links": ["{\"text\":\"income\",\"href\":\"/content/dam/usa/pdf/2017m_10.pdf\",\"desc\":\"This is a short description\"}", "{\"text\":\"Real Return\",\"href\":\"/content/dam/usa/pdf/singlepg.pdf\",\"desc\":\"This is a short description why to consider this\"}"],
        "moreLink": "/content/us/home"
      }, {
        "title": "ALLOCATION",
        "description": "This is a short description",
        "links": ["{\"text\":\"fund\",\"href\":\"/content/dam/usa/pdf/2017m_10.pdf\",\"desc\":\"This is a short description\"}", "{\"text\":\"ETF\",\"href\":\"/content/dam/usa/pdf/2017m_10.pdf\",\"desc\":\"This is a short description\"}", "{\"text\":\"Active/Passive\",\"href\":\"/content/dam/usa/pdf/sat02017m_10.pdf\",\"desc\":\"This is a short description\"}"],
        "moreLink": "/content/us/home"
      }]
    }
  }]
}
```

In this payload, the nested links section is a JSON string.

In my API, when I consume the payload, I should be able to send a pure JSON object to my front end. This structure will different across all endpoints, so I want a generic way to convert entire object to JSON.

Comment: tried JSON.dump

Comment: `JSON.parse();`

Comment: this would be easier if you add some of your code from your API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just parse then links content to JSON and respond the result to user from node.js server: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/lekhnath/cy0L5v0e/) is working example.

```
//ES6
let res = {
  "Page Title": "Home",
  "Page Description": "Sample Description",
  "Key Words": "test1, test2, test 3",
  "sections": [{
    "Lineup": {
      "title": "Our Project Family",
      "strategy": [{
        "title": "ASHJASH BASED",
        "description": "This is a short description",
        "links": ["{\"text\":\"income\",\"href\":\"/content/dam/usa/pdf/2017m_10.pdf\",\"desc\":\"This is a short description\"}", "{\"text\":\"Real Return\",\"href\":\"/content/dam/usa/pdf/singlepg.pdf\",\"desc\":\"This is a short description why to consider this\"}"],
        "moreLink": "/content/us/home"
      }, {
        "title": "ALLOCATION",
        "description": "This is a short description",
        "links": ["{\"text\":\"fund\",\"href\":\"/content/dam/usa/pdf/2017m_10.pdf\",\"desc\":\"This is a short description\"}", "{\"text\":\"ETF\",\"href\":\"/content/dam/usa/pdf/2017m_10.pdf\",\"desc\":\"This is a short description\"}", "{\"text\":\"Active/Passive\",\"href\":\"/content/dam/usa/pdf/sat02017m_10.pdf\",\"desc\":\"This is a short description\"}"],
        "moreLink": "/content/us/home"
      }]
    }
  }]
}

res.sections = res.sections.map(
  section => {
    section.Lineup.strategy = section.Lineup.strategy.map(
      strategy => {
        strategy.links = strategy.links.map(
          link => JSON.parse(link)
        )

        return strategy;
      }
    )

    return section;
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where only the first layer of JSON was an object, with the rest as json strings, when the object was passed from server to client, so found the following code useful on my client side to traverse the JSON object and convert anything it can into an object

just pass the object into the convert_to_obj function:

```
// Define recursive function to convert
function convert_to_obj(obj) {

    for(let k in obj) {
        try {
            obj[k] = JSON.parse(obj[k])

            if(obj[k] instanceof Object) {
                convert_to_obj(obj[k])
            }
        }
        catch { null }
        }
        return obj
    }
```

```
convert_to_obj(myJSON)
```